# Monotouch UICalendar Portrait Weekview

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm using the UICalendar library from github that allows for the built-in iOS calendar look and feel.

The weekview doesn't work in portrait view. What I would like to do is push my own DVC to in it's place when it's in portrait view. However, I cannot figure out where the view is being created and pushed to the view in the project. I've mainly been looking in `CalendarView.cs`

I actually imported the calendar code into my project so that I can make changes to the calendar and interact with my project directly. If anyone could help me on how to push my custom dvc when "Week" is selected in portrait mode, that would be fantastic!

Cheers

Calendar library : https://github.com/Clancey/UICalendar

Comment: A link to the calendar library you use could prove useful :-)

Comment: Sorry, it's added now

Comment: What does DVC mean? `DialogViewController` of Xamarin's `MonoTouch.Dialog`.

Comment: Please be a bit more concrete in your issue:

 - If you wanna to show your own `UIViewController` instead of WeekView, you can assign `LandscapeLeftView` and `LandscapeRightView` properties of `RotatingCalendarView`to your `UIView`;
 - If you wanna to use `UICalendar`'s `weekview` in portrait mode, it is also possible. I didn't understand @Clancey code complete, why it`s impossible to use week view in portrait mode. Seems like with a small patch it could be done;
 - If you wanna to use your own `UIViewController` for one of portrait view mode, there will be larger patch to `UICalendar`.

Comment: I mean `DialogViewController` from `MonoTouch.Dialog`. Thank you for all of the information. I want to show my own UIViewController for the portrait view when the user clicks "Week" and is in portrait mode. However, I cannot figure out how to do that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done through the `setupCustomInitialisation` method.

It would be `Case 2:` modify everything under that case so that you could add your view

`CalendarView.cs` line 719